# How to apply public proxy into python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

```
proxy_list = [
    "68.183.143.134",
    "209.13.186.20",
    "207.2.120.15",
    "41.77.188.131",
    "50.231.172.74",
    "50.174.145.14"
]

df = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    link = row['Link']
    name = row['Text']
    # link have product name
    url = f"<domain or third party url>/{link}"

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
    }
    chosen_proxy = proxy_list[index % len(proxy_list)]

    proxies = {
        "http": f"http://{chosen_proxy}",
        "https": f"http://{chosen_proxy}",
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

This is a Python script which has used proxy list to call a request but i am gettin error like :
**Unable to connect to proxy', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f544d220490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out')))**

I have generated proxy_list from free proxy website such as a *https://free-proxy-list.net/*